# How many Kib of address memory can be used

Tags: memory

The question I have is about addressable memory. Here is the question:

***A low-cost von Neumann machine has an address bus of 16 bits. In this computer, a unit of addressable memory is two bytes. How many KiB of addressable memory can be used?***

To work this out I first need to do 2^16 = 65,536 so this would be 64Kib. However the sentence about the unit of addressable memory is two bytes, do I, therefore, do 64/2 = 32kib, or because a unit is 2 bytes, which is 16 bits, then the answer would be 64Kib.

The answer given to me is 128Kib because they did 2^16 = 64Kib * 2 Bytes = 128Kib, but why did they * 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is since the smallest unit of addressable memory is *two* bytes, you can't address individual bytes.

Since you can't address individual bytes and you want every value that you can send over the address bus to refer to a different address, you should come up with an addressing scheme such as the following:

The address 0x0 (sent on the bus) means 'the first 2 bytes' of memory (e.g. bytes 0 and 1), the address value 0x1 (as sent on the bus) means the next 2 bytes of memory (e.g. bytes 2 and 3), and so on.